# DQL complex query in Symfony2 application

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

I have this situation in my model:

Product belongs to a Category.
TransactionDetail has Product, price and quantity.
Transaction has TransactionDetails and date.
Shop has Transactions.
Group has Shops.

They are Doctrine entities and they are properly related. (I don't paste the classes, it would be too long).

Thing is I need to query the model to obtain the total products sold (SUM TransactionDetail.quantity) and the total money (SUM TransactionDetail.quantity * TransactionDetail.prize), grouped by Product, From the Transactions of Products of a certain Category in a certain Group that happened in a range of dates.

Ok, I did this in plain SQL and it would be something like

```
select TransactionDetail.product, SUM(TransactionDetail.quantity) as quantity, SUM(TransactionDetail.quantity*TransactionDetail.prize) as euros
from TransactionDetail 
left join Transaction 
on TransactionDetail.transaction = Transaction.id 
left join Product 
on TransactionDetail.product = Product.id 
left join Group 
on Transaction.shop = Group.shop 
where Product.category = :paramCategoryId 
and Group.id = :paramGroupId 
group by TransactionDetail.product
```

The thing is I have NO IDEA about how do I put this in a DQL query (as plain SQL is not recommended, and I really would like to have a better understanding of the power of DQL).

Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance.

=============================================================================
EDIT:

State of the art query:

```
SELECT d, p, 
SUM(d.quantity) as quantity, SUM(d.quantity*d.prize) as euros
FROM TransactionDetail d
LEFT JOIN d.transaction t
LEFT JOIN d.product p
LEFT JOIN t.shop s 
LEFT JOIN s.groups g
ON s.id MEMBER OF g.shops
WHERE p.category = :category
AND g.id = :group
AND t.date > :from
AND t.date < :to
GROUP BY p
```

Problems: s.groups is a collection, and so is g.shops. I don't know how in the world this query must be done.

Comment: haha, power of dql. it helps a lot for simple queries, you don't have to select *.

Comment: Lol. I guess you're not a fan. But I'm sure there will be some specialist that will enlighten me :P

Comment: just answered you below :) after my troll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hand written, no insurance it works. You'll notice that DQL is **not** about **tables**, but **objects**.

So JOINS are actually done on object **properties**, not columns. (That's why it depends on your entity classes.

Also, you **can't** fetch data if you don't fetch the **root entity** first (`detail` in this case).

Also, expressions like `quantity * prize` could possibly not work.

Using just DQL query:

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery('
    SELECT detail, product, 
    SUM(detail.quantity) as quantity, SUM(detail.quantity*detail.prize) as euros
    FROM TransactionDetail detail
    LEFT JOIN detail.transaction transaction
    LEFT JOIN detail.product product
    LEFT JOIN transaction.group product ON group.shop = transaction.shop
    WHERE product.category = :category
    AND group.id = :group
    GROUP BY product
');

$results = $query->execute();
```

In some cases, using native sql is better: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder

and even the only choice.
PS: I lied, you can create your own DQL functions to make some specific stuff: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

Comment: thanks. just one thing... "ON group.shop = transaction.shop" is not possible. group.shop does not exist. group.shopS is a collection of shops. May "ON transaction.shop MEMBER OF group.shops" work?

Comment: have a look here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: Yes, I understand the JOIN types, but none of them seem to suit me for my purpose here. I'm stuck again.

Comment: why in your sql you have Group.shop then ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it on the go, the correct sql is "WHERE Transaction.shop IN (select shop ids from the group)", and not a JOIN.

Comment: As I said, the solution could be: custom DQL (user defined functions)

Comment: Hope it helps! I'd be curious to know if you succceded to make custom JOINS. Just remembered this: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/368 about arbitrary joins.

Comment: Hey, if you fancy helping me with my next debugging problem, feel free to do it :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360908/doctrine-query-syntax-error-in-multiple-join