# Doctrine query syntax error in multiple join

Tags: symfony, syntax, doctrine, dql

I'm trying to query the model in my Symfony2 project, and I have a little problem that I can't figure out. Check this out:

```
$q2 = 
  'SELECT 
    p.code, 
    p.desc, 
    SUM(d.quantity) as quantity, 
    SUM(d.quantity*d.prize) as euros
  FROM 
    Product p 
  JOIN 
    TransactionDetail d
  JOIN 
    d.transaction t
  WHERE 
    d.product IN :array 
  AND 
    t.shop = :shop
  GROUP BY 
    p.code';
$query2 = $this->em->createQuery($q2)
  ->setParameter('shop', $shop)->setParameter('array', $array);
$result = $query2->getResult();
```

And I get this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 248: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 't'
```

I don't understand it. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should link TransactionDetail with another entity :

Currently :

```
JOIN 
    TransactionDetail d
```

Should be:

```
JOIN 
    p.transactionDetail d
```

Comment: But it is not like that. "Product p" does not have a transactionDetail attribute. TransactionDetail has a product attribute.

Comment: THen, you can't do it. You have to make the Product aware of Detail to join it. (Use a inverse relation on product (ManyToOne/OneToMany).